# I can't use zsh alias command from ipython

Tags: zsh, ipython

I found that  I couldn't use alias command for zsh to  work in ipython  like `! alias_command` but `! system_command` did work  . Who can help me with this ?  Also ,the self-defined function in .zshrc can't work for me in ipython .

Comment: You would have to write a wrapper script that sources the files defining the shell functions first.  ipython can't know about them.

Comment: As far as I see `ipython` does not use zsh.

Comment: IPython will run the commands with Python's `os.system()` function, or equivalent - but I'm not sure how that picks which shell to use.